# Efficient way to create variant playlists from mp4 for HLS

Tags: ios, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am totally new to video encoding and options, and just learned about Apple's HLS requirements.

So far, I've been able to get something working for my iOS app. However, I find the entire process to be very slow and manual. Now, having to repeat this for several more locales (video translations), I can't imagine there isn't a better way.

#### Controlling bitrate

To have control over the bitrate, I use HandBrake to create a new .mp4 file with the appropriate video encoder setting, for each bitrate I want (192k, 400k, 1m, etc.). THEN, I move onto creating the playlists. This alone takes several minutes--is there a better way? `tsrecompressor` seemed close, but it just streams to a local port and doesn't save any playlists.

#### Creating playlists from MP4

Then I use Apple's suite of command-line tools (`mediafilesegmenter`, `variantplaylistcreator`, `mediastreamvalidator`, `hlsreport`) to generate the playlists, combine into a master playlist, validate, etc. I suppose this part could be somewhat automated with a script. I've seen others use FFMPEG, but I think the latter 3 Apple tools would still need to be sequentially applied.

Do you see anything that can be obviously optimized?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “optimized” here. But you can write a script (handbrake has a CLI tool) or just just ffmpeg to do everything (there are a million examples of how to do that on the internet is you search for them). Video transcoding is slow, nothing you can do about that except to use hardware accelerator (again, google can tell you how to do that as well)

Comment: What us your end goal here? Just experimenting with video compression? Or are your trying to build a service?

Comment: @szatmary thanks for the insight. I was hesitant to use ffmpeg since Apple recommended using their suite of tools, but if I have to do more of these, I might use ffmpeg. Good to know that video transcoding is slow.

Comment: @SrikanthK. I was just trying to set up HLS streaming for videos that my app is serving (otherwise we'd be violating the Apple requirements). So far we are only supporting two locales, so I just went with this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading - it looks like you are creating different mp4s at each size, and then the HLS streams?

With FFMPEG, you can create all the HLS streams/playlists without creating all the mp4s first.  That will cut out ~ 50% of the encoding you are doing :)

There are also services that can create host and deliver your HLS streams for you - saving you all the time of creating the videos (I work for one - api.video).